# How do you exclude and include fields in Sequelize by scope?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, scope, sequelize.js

```
const getMe = await UserModel.scope("test").findOne({
  where: {
    uid: uid,
  },
  include: [
    {
      model: GroupModel,
      as: "groups",
      include: ["product"],
    },
  ],
});
```

I am trying to manage excluding fields and allowing fields based on scope.

```
defaultScope: {
  attributes: {
    exclude: ["id"],
  },
},
scopes: {
  test: {
    atrributes: {
      exclude: ["email"],
    },
  },
},
```

associations

```
UserModel.hasMany(GroupModel, { as: "groups" });

Groupmodel.belongsTo(UserModel, {
  foreignKey: "userId",
  as: "user",
});
GroupModel.belongsTo(ProductModel, {
  foreignKey: "productId",
  as: "product",
});
```

As a test I am by default excluding "id", and with the test scope I am excluding "email". I have tried everything from `exclude` `include` setting `attributes` directly in the `findOne` call. Nothing works.

What is the proper way to exclude certain fields say for "Public" returns, and include all fields for an "Admin scope" of some sort?

Comment: What is the version of your Sequelize ?

Comment: @UmerAbbas It is 6.12.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `defaultScope` like this.

```
defaultScope: {
    attributes: {
        exclude: ['email']
    }
}
```

When you do find query, it excludes "email" by default and use `unscoped` to disable the `defaultScope`.

```
// This should not return email
UserModel.findOne()

// Admin case: unscoped to disable defaultScope. This should return email.
UserModel.unscoped().findOne()
```

Alternatively, if you would like to be more explicit, you can have scope named "admin".

```
{
    defaultScope: {
        attributes: {
            exclude: ['email']
        }
    },
    scopes: {
        admin: {}  // No special options for admin scope. No exclusion. 
    }
}
```

This way when you do find query, it is excluding "email" by default. Then, if you use "admin" scope, it won't exclude anything.

```
// This should not return email
UserModel.findOne()

// Admin case: This should overwrite the defaultScope.
UserModel.scope('admin').findOne()
```

`.scope(str)` function overwrites the `defaultScope`, so any options in `defaultScope` is ignored when you use `.scope(str)`.

Comment: Thank you for that, the ```admin: {}``` portion explains what I did wrong. the exclusion not being there overrides the default. I did find in the documentation that Scopes apply to .find, .findAll, .count, .update, .increment and .destroy, and not .findOne so that may be why nothing was working anytime I did a .findOne().

Comment: it should apply to `findOne` as well.  I tested and works fine for `findOne`.

Comment: Hmmm ok let me redo one of the functions for ```findOne``` and retest. thank you very much.